# Store value to arraylist from json data and populate view holder

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am making an application in which I am receiving some JSON data from url as **shown in this** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGZyF.png). Basically every date array has 5 objects in it and I am using this **piece of code** to get the session from and session to values from each date array

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
 JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
      Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
              key = iter.next();
              JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);
              sessionsfrom = new ArrayList<String>();

              JSONObject datesObjectt = datesArray.getJSONObject(4);

              for (int i = 0; i < datesArray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject datesObject = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                  sessionsfrom.add(datesObject.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject.getString("session_to") );
                  mBaseRecyclerAdapter.setItems(sessionsfrom);
                                    }
```

In the last line I am storing all the session from and session to values in arraylist and put in adapter of recycler view. These sessions are creating time slots in the app as shown in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryg4f.png) 
Now what I want is that I have to save **bookingFound value** from json to somewhere with session from and session to value i.e. it doesnot show in app but in the background of each slot, every value of bookingFoung must be stored so that when populating **viewholder** I can check which bookingFound slots return true and which return false so that I can change the color of slots to grey if bookingFound true

To populate view holder I have the following **piece of code**

```
   private BaseRecyclerAdapter<String, CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder> mBaseRecyclerAdapter = new BaseRecyclerAdapter<String, CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder>(CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder.class, R.layout.item_court_details_availability_time) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder viewHolder, String model, int position) {
       // SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        //String name = preferences.getString("slotfound", "");
        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setText(model);
        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked(model));
        /*for (int i = 0; i < bookingcheck.size(); i++) {
            if (bookingcheck.get(i).contains("true")) {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details_disable);
            } else {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details);
            }
        }*/

    }
};
```

In this code, the commented part is what I tried but it doesnot worked. I put bookingFound values in bookingcheck arraylist and then checked if it contains true then slots disabled otherwise enabled but it doesnot work... Please Help

Conclusion

1- store bookingFound json value just like session from and session to values

2- use that value to enable or disable slots on the application

Comment: but my question is not about that :(

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix

use

```
datesObject.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject.getString("session_to")+"$"+datesObject.get("bookingFound").getAsBoolean()
```

While Displaying Sessions use

```
String Session = "02:00 AM - 02:30 AM$true";
String[] separated = currentString.split("$");
separated[0]; // this will contain "02:00 AM - 02:30 AM"
separated[1]; // this will contain "true"

for (int i = 0; i < bookingcheck.size(); i++) {
            if (bookingcheck.get(i).contains("true")) {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details_disable);
            } else {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change some code. fist, create a custom object for the session to enhance the performance and the design of code

```
public class SessionModel {

    String sessionFrom;
    String sessionTo;
    boolean sessionFound;


    public SessionModel(String sessionFrom, String sessionTo, boolean sessionFound) {
        this.sessionFrom = sessionFrom;
        this.sessionTo = sessionTo;
        this.sessionFound = sessionFound;
    }


    public String getSessionFrom() {
        return sessionFrom;
    }

    public void setSessionFrom(String sessionFrom) {
        this.sessionFrom = sessionFrom;
    }

    public String getSessionTo() {
        return sessionTo;
    }

    public void setSessionTo(String sessionTo) {
        this.sessionTo = sessionTo;
    }

    public boolean isSessionFound() {
        return sessionFound;
    }

    public void setSessionFound(boolean sessionFound) {
        this.sessionFound = sessionFound;
    }
}
```

then create an arraylist of this object and use this arraylist in adapter "after for loop finish"

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
    Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
    key = iter.next();
    JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);
    sessionsfrom = new ArrayList<SessionModel>();

    JSONObject datesObjectt = datesArray.getJSONObject(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < datesArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject datesObject = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);
    sessionsfrom.add(SessionModel(datesObject.getString("session_from"), datesObject.getString("session_to"), datesObject.getboolean("bookinFound")));
    }
    mBaseRecyclerAdapter.setItems(sessionsfrom);
```

in in your adapter

```
private BaseRecyclerAdapter<String, CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder> mBaseRecyclerAdapter = new BaseRecyclerAdapter<String, CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder>(CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder.class, R.layout.item_court_details_availability_time) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(CourtDetailsTimeViewHolder viewHolder, SessionModel model, int position) {

        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setText(model.getgetSessionFrom+"-"+model.getSessionTo);
        viewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked(model));

            if (model.get(i).isSessionFound()) {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details_disable);
            } else {
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                viewHolder.mCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slctr_bg_cb_challenges_details);
            }


    }
};
```

Comment: after changing to seesionsfrom = ArrayList<SessionModel> then on this line "sessionsfrom.add(datesObject.getString("session_from"), datesObject.getString("session_to"), datesObject.getboolean("bookinFound"));"

Comment: it saying model.sessionModel in arraylist cannot be applied to java.lang.string

Comment: Change the (String sessionsfrom) to (SessionModel sessionfrom)

Comment: sessiosnfrom was already an arraylist. After you said to make model then following changes are done. i.e. ArrayList<SessionModel> sessionsfrom = new ArrayList<SessionModel>();

Comment: Ok brother let me check with this

Comment: setItems
(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
in BaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied
to
(java.util.ArrayList<com.sportsvenue.sooryen.model.SessionModel>)

Comment: now its saying this on this line "  mBaseRecyclerAdapter.setItems(sessionsfrom);"

Comment: Good, I edited the code and remove redundant for loop. Please edit the code to solve last problem

Comment: Ok iam doing this